# Monitor a 5 A system with a compatible current sensor

Tags: sensor, integrated-circuit, current-measurement, control

I need to monitor a system that can consume up to 5 A of current on 5 V. Its components consume between tens and a few hundreds of mA each. A 10 mA resolution is acceptable.
I need this monitor to have a digital comm output (i2c is good).
When searching for a suitable current sensor I came across components that either could take high currents but not to have a good resolution, or they were not good for currents above a couple of A.

I have seen the [ina3221](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina3221.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1624870470458&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fina3221) but I can’t find the max current I can put through its main line.

**What IC can I use for my application?**

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Comment: *but I cant find the max current I can put through its main line.* - because the current would depend on the shunt resistor. This IC is basically measuring the voltage on the shunt resistor rather than current directly.

Comment: *...but I cant find the max current I can put through its main line.* Then you need to read and **understand** the datasheet more carefully. The INA3221 measures **voltages**. So you need a **shunt resistor** through which the current will flow. The current is limited by the shunt resistor, not the IC.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so how can I determine if it can detect the current in the resolution I need?

Comment: The datasheet tells all. You want 10mV resolution over 5A.that’s 1 in 500. The chip has a resolution of 13bits, thats +/-4096. You should be able to achieve a resolution of slightly more than 1mA.

Comment: thank you @Kartman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I2C sensor INA260 from Adafruit or MIKROE-4039 (digikey) has internal shunt resistor, Kelvin current sensor, and claims to handle 15A at resolution of 1.5mA. Also measures voltage and calculates power. There is a datasheet for the chip available via keyword search.

Answer (score 0):

the ina3221 can fit this application.
it is a current sensor based on deriving the voltage difference across a shunt resistor.
it is important to use a shunt resistor thet is rated for the power flowing through it.